# Can I use a Miele washing machine for US (2 x 110V) with 220V plug

Tags: appliances

Suppose that I have a low end Miele washing machine (say, WWH860WCS) designed for the US market, with 2 x 110V plugs. Very naively, I am guessing that the machines being made in Germany would be mostly identical to those offered in Europe, and the 2 inputs are, roughly speaking, connected in series to produce 220V. Now the question is, can I safely use the machine by plugging one of the inputs to 220V and leaving the second plug idle?

Or is there another (sufficiently simple) way of using such a washing machine in a 220V country?

Thank you.

Comment: Miele used to make 240V/60Hz machines for the US market that were compatible with the European 230V/50Hz supply. In US installations they are pugged into a sub-panel/splitter to share the receptacle with a dryer. Newer machines like yours list the required 120 or 230 voltage on the plate of the machine.

Answer (score 8):

It's not supplied with 2 cords.

> The washing machine is supplied with *a* 5’ 3“ (1.6 m) long, 3 wire cord, ending in *a* NEMA 5-15P plug, ready for connection to *a* 120 V, 15 A, 60 Hz, AC power supply.

Instructions page 84.

If you see a second cord-and-plug, it's for the dryer, which is a completely different appliance.

Your plan is not going to work for several reasons.  First, there is no way to develop 120V from a Euro style 230V supply, except by using a large transformer.  (the hokey travel adapters will not work; they use electronic trickery that will not work with a big motor load like a washer.)  Second, the power frequency is wrong, and the washer cares because it has a big motor that will now be running at the wrong speed with the wrong reactance, and will tend to overheat.

So really, you need a rather hefty electronic sine-wave inverter that would turn 230VAC/50Hz into 120VAC/60Hz, but this is not some $50 travel adapter off Amazon, it's a large multi-hundred dollar machine.

### Do not ship large electric appliances across oceans.

It's a waste of fuel.  They won't work. Just sell em on Craigslist and buy replacements off Craigslist once you're there.

Comment: Besides 50/60 Hz washing machines with inverter motors, 
the shipping -or -not - decision may depend on the ocean. For the South Atlantic Ocean between Africa and South America, or the Pacific between Asia and Australia, a transport could be a good solution, if there is still some space in the moving container. The transport of a new washing machine from the manufacturer (Europe, China) to the new location might use much more fuel, if the container ships are similar or are identical. But the transport locks must be installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two plugs on an appliance, at least in the City of Chicago, and Cook County, IL, which follows the National Electrical code. I don't know about un-incorporated areas.

Problems:

1. Most (all?) people expect that if you find the power cord and pull it out from the wall, the device is safe.
2. Pretty sure its against the NEC
3. Most houses in the USA are supplied with two wires with a potential of around 240Vac between them. Then, to create 120Vac, the center is connected to ground. The circuit breaker panel is then loaded evenly with breakers to achieve this even split (and everybody else on the same transformer). When you plug into a 120Vac outlet, you are getting one hot (black) and one at near-earth potential (white). Then the green wire is for safety (the NEC uses more technical terms), it is connected to the a bus bar inside the panel for all whites and greens. So ... if you plug one plug into one 120V outlet, and another into another 120V outlet, you are either getting 120-120 = 0 or 120 - -120 = 240 Oh noes!
4. It is recommended that the dishwasher not have a plug.
5. You won't get an electrician to wire it up for you.

Note that there are 240Vac appliances in the US, they use two-pole breakers. Some examples are hot water heater, electric dryer, air conditioner.

There are other reasons, but I don't want you to even think about it.

Honestly, take the advice of others, just leave it in Europe, you are going to have all sorts of problems between metric and SAE/Imperial. If the device catches on fire and it does not have an appropriate approval (used to be UL but there are others now), and burns your house down, you might get NOTHING from the insurance company. Not an insurance expert.

Note in Europe the wires are black, brown, blue, can't remember off the top of my head which is which.

Source, have MSEE, used to work at Bosch Power Tools, testing products designed for USA/Canada/Mexico, and then UK & Continental Europe. Have read parts of the NEC.

Comment: It's a UL issue.  Underwriter's Laboratories is the curator of the appliance safety standards, called the White Book.  UL or other NRTL must approve any appliance sold in the US.  Selling appliances which are not thusly approved is illegal. *steely gaze at the Amazon warehouse, which cheats and makes you the importer*

Comment: Wiring colours are Green + Yellow, Brown and Blue, not black (anymore). That’s E, N, L respectively. I don’t see how the wiring colours make any difference to this answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the great variety of different plugs in different countries, they all have one feature in common: power outlets are female sockets, and inlets are male plugs. This is to prevent exposure humans to live pins.

**If an appliance has two plugs, they cannot be connected together in any way.** If they were, if you removed one plug and left the other plugged in, the pins could be live and you could electrocute yourself by touching them.

I would be very surprised to find consumer equipment with two plugs. I've seen industrial equipment with a single phase plug for the control panel and a three phase plug for a large motor (which may be operated by the control panel with **complete** electrical isolation via a contactor relay.) Even then, there is usually a warning to disconnect all supplies before working on the equipment.

**If you really must use American equipment in Europe, there is (at least in the UK and I assume it is the same elsewhere) a simple solution: Buy a building site transformer.** Building sites in the UK use a form of 110V. Actually it is a tapped 55V-0V-55V with a centre earth. The idea is to limit the max voltage to 55V to avoid electrocution. It's not the same as the 0V-110V used in the USA, but it can work.

Examples are here https://www.screwfix.com/c/electrical-lighting/site-transformers/cat830094

That said, the appliance may not work as intended, especially a washing machine, where the  lower frequency (50hz instead of 60hz) will affect the motor. Best case it runs at 5/6 of its intended speed. Worst case, motors and transformers burn out because lower frequency through a coil leads to higher current (though this is unlikely.)

**Unless you have a very special use case, sell your American appliances and buy European ones when you get here.** There are exceptions - I have used specialist 110V American made laboratory equipment in Europe, using a transformer like the one described above, following an assessment of how the different frequency and centre earth would affect it.